# Changing CSS using JQuery for multiple, dynamically created divs (unknown div IDs)

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a bunch of color swatches from an array using PHP.

Here is the PHP code (I've removed some of the colors from the array, to make the code shorter, in practice there are many more).

```
$colors = array(
        "Light Blue"=>"198,248,253",
        "Medium Blue"=>"112,204,246",
        "Blue"=>"84,140,242",
        "Dark Blue"=>"52,55,199",
        "Dark Green"=>"53,172,58",
        "Light Green"=>"191,235,104"
    );

    echo "<label>Color:</label>";

    foreach ($colors as $colorName => $colorCode) {
        echo "<div style='background-color:rgb(".$colorCode.");' class='swatch' id='".str_replace(" ","_",$colorName)."'></div>";

    }
```

I would like, when the user selects (clicks) a swatch, a css border is added to highlight the user's selection.

I have tried the following JQuery, but can't seem to get it working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', 'div', function () {

        $(this.id).css('border','solid 1px black');

});
```

});

I'm sure it is something rather simple, simply down to my lack of experience with JQuery. Any help appreciated. Thanks,

Dingo Bruce

Comment: A tip not directly related to your question: Instead of setting specific CSS properties with JS, add a class (using jQuerys `.addClass()`) and put the style (`border: solid 1px black;` in this case) in the CSS for that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know you have a `class` given to each dynamically created `element`. So just use `event delegation` and add `css` to clicked `class` rather say `element` as follows:

```
$(document).on('click','.swatch',function(){
    $(this).css('border','solid 1px black'); //$(this) refers to current element here
});
```

As per @Anders comment if you want to remove border from all other `divs` with class `swatch` and want to keep only on the current clicked item below will be the piece of code which helps you to achieve the same.

```
$(document).on('click','.swatch',function(){
    $('.swatch').css('border','0px');
    //if you don't have any extra inline styling then you can directly remove your 
    //style attribute with $('.swatch').removeAttr('style'); Use either of one
    $(this).css('border','solid 1px black'); //$(this) refers to current element here
});
```

Comment: Also, if you want to remove the border from the previously selected `<div>` you should add `$('.swatch').css('border','0px');` before the line adding the border to the newly selected `<div>`.

Comment: Well Thank you @Anders.. Updated answer!!

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm and I've taken another step forward with my understanding of JQuery.

Comment: anytime!! Happy coding.. :)